# Obtener una fecha a partir del numero de dia

Tags: vb6

No encuentro una manera de convertir el resultado de:

```
PDia = DateDiff("y", "1/1/" & Year(SeleFecha1), SeleFecha1)
```

Donde

```
    SeleFecha1 = 2/1/2018


 PDia = 31
```

Ahora, quiero restar ***5*** a ***Pdia*** y volverlo a convertir a una Fecha.

¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo siguiendo este metodo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pregunta no es muy clara. Sin embargo suponiendo que `SeleFecha1` es una fecha. Lo siguiente debería proporcionarte lo que necesitas.

```
DateAdd("d",-5,SeleFecha1)
```

Comment: Precisamente en el código SeleFecha1 le era asignada una fecha. Sin embargo la función que propones me fue útil y la estoy utilizando en conjunto al código existente, con a eso resolví mi problema. Gracias agente Bond.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno al final de cuentas cree mi propia funcion. (No es muy sofisticada ni nada, pero era lo que necesitaba).

```
Function FechaDesdeEntero(ByVal Entero As Integer, ByVal Año As Integer) As String
```

`TOPMEN:`

```
Select Case Año
Case 2000 Or 2004 Or 2008 Or 2012 Or 2016 Or 2020 Or 2024 Or 2028 Or 2032 Or 2036 Or 2040 Or 2044 Or 2048 Or 2052 Or 2056 Or 2060 Or 2064 Or 2068 Or 2072 Or 2076 Or 2080 Or 2084 Or 2088 Or 2092 Or 2096 Or 2100

    Select Case Entero
        Case 1 To 31 'ENERO
            FechaDesdeEntero = "1/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 32 To 60   'FEBRERO
            Entero = Entero - 31
            FechaDesdeEntero = "2/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 61 To 91   'MARZO
            Entero = Entero - 60
            FechaDesdeEntero = "3/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 92 To 121  'ABRIL
            Entero = Entero - 91
            FechaDesdeEntero = "4/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 122 To 152 'MAYO
            Entero = Entero - 121
            FechaDesdeEntero = "5/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 153 To 182 'JUNIO
            Entero = Entero - 152
            FechaDesdeEntero = "6/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 183 To 213 'JULIO
            Entero = Entero - 182
            FechaDesdeEntero = "7/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 214 To 244 ''AGOSTO
            Entero = Entero - 213
            FechaDesdeEntero = "8/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 245 To 274 'SEPTIEMBRE
            Entero = Entero - 244
            FechaDesdeEntero = "9/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 275 To 305 'OCTUBRE
            Entero = Entero - 274
            FechaDesdeEntero = "10/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 306 To 335 'NOVIEMBRE
            Entero = Entero - 305
            FechaDesdeEntero = "11/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 336 To 366 'DICIEMBRE
            Entero = Entero - 335
            FechaDesdeEntero = "12/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case Is > 366
        Año = Año + 1
        Entero = Entero - 366
        GoTo TOPMEN:
    End Select

Case Else

    Select Case Entero
        Case 1 To 31 'Enero
             FechaDesdeEntero = "1/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 32 To 59 'Febrero
             Entero = Entero - 31
             FechaDesdeEntero = "2/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 60 To 90 'Marzo
             Entero = Entero - 59
             FechaDesdeEntero = "3/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 91 To 120 'Abril
             Entero = Entero - 90
             FechaDesdeEntero = "4/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 121 To 151 'Mayo
             Entero = Entero - 120
             FechaDesdeEntero = "5/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 152 To 181 ' Junio
             Entero = Entero - 151
             FechaDesdeEntero = "6/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 182 To 212 'Julio
             Entero = Entero - 181
             FechaDesdeEntero = "7/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 213 To 243 'Agosto
             Entero = Entero - 212
             FechaDesdeEntero = "8/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 244 To 273 'Septiembre
             Entero = Entero - 243
             FechaDesdeEntero = "9/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 274 To 304 'Octubre
             Entero = Entero - 273
             FechaDesdeEntero = "10/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 305 To 334 'Noviembre
             Entero = Entero - 304
             FechaDesdeEntero = "11/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case 335 To 365 'Diciembre
             Entero = Entero - 334
             FechaDesdeEntero = "12/" & Entero & "/" & Año
        Case Is > 365 'Se pasaron de corneto
        Año = Año + 1
        Entero = Entero - 365
        GoTo TOPMEN:
    End Select
```

End Select

End Function